# Resetting mysql root password

Tags: mysql

I understand that this is the safest way to change or reset mysql root password. I'm doing it because 8 times out of 10 the installation program won't prompt me for a root password.

So I run commands:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
sudo mysql -u root
use mysql;
```

Then, depending on your version of mysql or maria you're using you type:

```
update user set password=PASSWORD("mynewpassword") where User='root';
```

or

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';
```

In my case I typed the first one. Then I refresh privileges by:
`flush privileges;` and then I exit out of mysql by typing: `quit`.

At this point everything went well. Then I restart mysql server by:
`sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start`

I get "OK" from the terminal. However, when I attempt to log in as root
I get pleasant error message saying:
`ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'`

I'm 100% confident that I'm typing correct password. Why is this happening ?

Comment: Why did you use the first method, the second method seems safer.

Comment: As I said, the first method supposedly work on my version of mysql. I suppose I could try the other one too but it shouldn't work.

Comment: Yeah, it's hard to see what you might be doing wrong. But if I had a nickel for every time someone said they were 100% confident that they typed the right thing....

Comment: @Barmar  I don't think I'm stupid enough to type wrong password or misspell 5 times in a row.

Comment: Which version is it? I was surprised once with MySQL 5.7. when I tried to copy a user to a new server with `GRANT ... IDENTIFIED BY '*KDFJIED...'`. It then built to my surprise the hash of the hash of the password.

Comment: There are lots of questions about problems resetting root password at dba.stackexchange.com, which is where this question belongs as well.

Comment: @AmanKumar  I do appreciate all the help I'm getting from community. Your updated answer didn't work. All the changing statements I've used so far resulted in "Query OK" but it doesn't take any effect on behaviour.

Comment: Out of despair I tried to reinstall mysql but that didn't help either.

Comment: @fancyPants   It is 10.0.31-MariaDB. For some reason when I type `sudo apt-get install mysql-server` I get Maria database instead. Allegedly it's a drop-in database server that is little bit more efficient than standard mysql server.

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved by backing up all important data and reinstalling the operating system. As turned out I had some broken packages that affected how mysql authentication worked. Standard steps to fix broken packages was no use so I wiped out HDD and started over.

MySQL was installed without any hiccups and was even prompted for a root password to be set. Now MySQL authentication works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this out :-**  It Works for me..!!

1. Stop the MySQL server process.

> `service mysql stop`

2. Start the MySQL (mysqld) server/daemon process with the –skip-grant-tables option so that it will not prompt for password.

> `mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables > /dev/null 2>&1 &`

3. Connect to mysql server as the root user. And Setup new mysql root account password.

> `mysql -u root -e "use mysql; update user set password=PASSWORD('NEW-PASSWORD') where User='root'; flush privileges;"`

4. Exit and restart the MySQL server.

> `service mysql restart`

**Note:** You may need to wait after `mysqld_safe` command, before you can run subsequent `mysql` command.

Now run :- `mysql -u root -p`